# Wordpress plugin - using esc_attr before mail - safe?

Tags: php, wordpress, email

i created a wordpress plugin in which i want to send an email to an address that has been inserted into a form. I use it like this:

```
$to_email = esc_attr($_POST['to_email']);
mail($to_email, ...
```

Is this safe in regards to spams etc or do i have to use another wordpress function, except esc_attr, to disable possible threats via this form?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace mail with wp_mail
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail

You need to check that the email address is set and a valid address. If it passes both tests then set it to the POST value. If it doesn't then set the value to false and don't proceed with attempting to send the email.

```
$to_email = ( isset( $_POST['to_email'] ) && is_email( $_POST['to_email'] ) ) ? $_POST['to_email'] : false;
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer indicated, you should use [wp_mail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) rather than mail().

Instead of esc_attr, I think you probably want to use [sanitize_email](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_email).  You can check to see if it is an email (i.e. contains '@', etc) with [is_email](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_email).